# explain the print strategy in below codes

Tags: python, for-loop, python-3.x

I started learning Python recently and while using lists I faced this problem.

Here I assigned some movie names to variable `movies`:

```
>>> movies = ["dragon","dragon warrior","kungfu","kungfu panda"]
```

after assigning, I used the `print` command to execute it:

```
>>> print(movies)
```

the output is as below:

```
['dragon', 'dragon warrior', 'kungfu', 'kungfu panda']
```

In the same way, when I started using a for-loop in lists with the same `print` command, the output is entirely different.  I can't understand how it changed because of the for-loop:

```
>>> for fav_movie in movies:
          print(fav_movie)
```

output:

```
dragon
dragon warrior
kungfu
kungfu panda
```

Why is the same print command working differently?

Comment: It sounds like you don't understand what the `for` loop does, which is a more fundamental issue. It might be easier to craft an answer that makes sense to you if we knew how far are you into your learning (because it's very easy to assume an intelligent novice understands a lot more than he actually does).

Comment: (guess)Do you refer to the fact that before it was printed `'dragon'` and afterwards it is printed only `dragon`(without delimiters)? You should look at the difference between `str` and `repr`(try `print(str("A"))` and `print(repr("A"))`). When doing `print(movies)` the `print` function calls `str(movies)` to obtain a string representation of the list. `str(movies)` calls `repr(movie)` for each movie and creates the final result. Calling `repr` on a string produces a string containing the delimiters, hence what you see.

Answer (score 2):

`print(movies)` prints the `str` version of the list object, while in the loop you're printing the `str` version of individual items inside the list.

```
>>> print(movies)
['dragon', 'dragon warrior', 'kungfu', 'kungfu panda']
```

is equivalent to:

```
>>> print(movies.__str__())   #or simply print(str(movies))
['dragon', 'dragon warrior', 'kungfu', 'kungfu panda']
```

Note that you're seeing quotes here in the list elements, that's because the representation used is the `repr` version of those objects. The `repr` version of the list would also contain quotes around it.

```
>>> repr(movies)
"['dragon', 'dragon warrior', 'kungfu', 'kungfu panda']"
```

`repr` is a computer friendly output and `str` is human friendly, a good example would be floats:

```
>>> x = 1.1 + 2.2
>>> print repr(x)
3.3000000000000003
>>> print str(x)
3.3
```

Also note that the string returned by `repr` can be re-used to generate that object using `eval`.

For more details read: [Difference between **str** and **repr** in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python).

Inside the loop you're printing the `str` version of each item:

```
>>> print(movies[0])
dragon
>>> print(movies[0].__str__())
dragon
>>> for movie in movies:
...     print(str(movie))
...     
dragon
dragon warrior
kungfu
kungfu panda
```

Comment: You could add that `str(movies)` uses `repr` to obtain the string representation of the list items(otherwise the OP can still wonder why they show differently).

Comment: @Bakuriu oh! I see what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

The first command you're printing the actual list object, the second you're looping through the list's elements and printing one by one.

Answer (score 1):

The first print statement is printing a list; while the second one is printing strings.

Answer (score 1):

That's how Python works.  Using `print(movies)` prints a string representation of the whole list `movies` where as:

```
for fav_movie in movies:
      print(fav_movie)
```

prints the items in `movies` one at a time.

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3]
>>> print(l)
[1, 2, 3]
>>> for i in l: print(i)
...
1
2
3
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to iCodez answer, it is worth noting that print will introduce a newline character. For example:

```
>>> import sys
>>> l = ["a", "b", "c"]
>>> print l
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> for i in l: print i
... 
a
b
c
>>> for i in l: sys.stdout.write(i)
... 
abc>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

`print(x)` does the following:

1.) If `x` is not a string, convert it to such by calling `x.__str__()`.

```
>>> 'Hello!'.__str__()
'Hello!'
>>> [1,2,3].__str__()
'[1, 2, 3]'
```

2.) Output that string

3.) Start a new line (you actually can turn that off).

---

`print(movies)` will actually do `print(movies.__str__())`, while

```
for movie in movies:
    print(movie)
```

will go through the movies, and print each movie separately. Since the movies are already strings, no conversion step is neccessary. And every movie gets its own line due to step 3.